# How does the heuristic for an A* algorithm change the traversal

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, heuristics

I am having some troubles understanding how the traversal of a graph will change from using a dikstras algorithm that will first look for the min value "road" to take to then go deeper into the tree.

How did the heuristic in a* cause a different traversal and overall different result

Well really appreciate a week constructed answer her because this is something I'm not really understand at this point.

Comment: Are you asking how the heuristic of A* makes it different from Dijkstra's, or how different heuristics for A* can lead to different parts of the search space being searched first?

Comment: Not sure if this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13031462/difference-and-advantages-between-dijkstra-a-star